# retrieve data from two tables where some values are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve student data who have posted a discussion in the forum as well as who never posted in a specific course
I write this request:

```
SELECT p.idp, p.age, p.speciality, f.categforum
FROM forum f
LEFT JOIN participant p
     ON f.idp=p.idp AND f.idc=4
```

but that return only list of student who have a post in a forum.
my result should be like that:

```
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
| idp | age | speciality | categforum |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
|  01 |  23 | computing  | NULL       |
|  02 |  25 | management | problem    |
|  03 |  35 | management | NULL       |
|  05 |  25 | computing  | social     |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
```

....
I have added `categforum` is `NULL` but that isn't workable.

Comment: Change left join to right join

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want all *participants*.  If so, that table should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.idp, p.age, p.speciality, f.categforum
FROM participant p LEFT JOIN
     forum f 
     ON f.idp = p.idp AND f.idc = 4 ;
```

You *could* also use `RIGHT JOIN`.  However, I almost never use `RIGHT JOIN`.  I find that `LEFT JOIN` is much easier to follow -- at least for people who read from left-to-right.  The idea of keeping all the rows in the *first* table is easier to follow than keeping all rows in the (yet-to-be-read) *last* table.

Answer (score 1):

Try Right join instead. 
 **Query**:

```
SELECT p.idp, p.age, p.speciality, f.categforum 
FROM forum f 
RIGHT JOIN participant p ON f.idp=p.idp 
AND f.idc=4
```

Comment: Perfect, that works very well !! thank you very much